# Why does upgrading Ubuntu to 20.04 is going to remove nodejs, mySQL workbench from the system?

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

while I am upgrading ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04, it is going to remove nodejs, mySQL workbench, etc from machine. Is there any option to prevent this from removing.

Answer (score 1):

Because Ubuntu 20.04 is missing libwebkit something, and mySQL Workbench depends on it. 
Same with nodejs. 
Either the version you installed or a dependency is not in the repositories.

So your package gets removed by apt.

See also 
[install MySQL-Workbench on Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/how-to-install-mysql-workbench-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts.html)

and 
[install MySQL on Ubuntu 20.04](https://linuxconfig.org/install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-linux)

When you issued `sudo apt install update-manager-core; sudo do-release-upgrade`, APT probably has shown you the following text

```
Calculating upgrade... Done 
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required
[...]libwebkit-something[...]
The following packages will be upgraded
[...]
The following packages will be installed 
[...]
AND
The following packages will be REMOVED: 
[...]mysql-workbench[...]
```